# Scala match case with multiple branch with if

Tags: scala

I have a match case with `if` and the expression is **always the same**.
I put some pseudo code:

```scala
value match {
  case A => same expression
  case B(_) if condition1 => same expression
  case _ if condition2 => same expression
  ...
  case _ => different expression //similar to an else
}
```

The match contains both `case object` (`case A`) matching and `case class`(`case B(_)`)

Is it the best practice?

Comment: For brevity, consider combining `if condition2` with subsequent guards into something like `case _ if condition2 | condition3 | condition4 => same expression`.

Comment: This code looks absolutely fine to me ... But style questions are out of topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to explain this code in words. "This function returns one of two values. The first is returned if the input is `A`. Or if the input is of type `B` and a condition holds. Oh, or if a different condition holds. Otherwise, it's the other value". That sounds incredibly complex to me.

I have to recommend breaking this down at least a bit. At minimum, you've got two target expressions, and which one is chosen depends on some predicate of `value`. That sounds like a `Boolean` to me. Assuming `value` is of some trait type `Foo` (which `A.type` and `B` extend), you could write

```
sealed trait Foo {
  def isFrobnicated: Boolean = this match {
    case A => true
    case B(_) if condition1 => true
    case _ => condition2
  }
}

...

if (value.isFrobnicated) {
  same expression
} else {
  different expression
}
```

Now the cognitive load is split into two different, smaller chunks of code to digest, and presumably `isFrobnicated` will be given a self-documenting name and a chunk of comments explaining why this distinction is important. Anyone reading the bottom snippet can simply understand "Oh, there's two options, based on the frobnication status", and if they want more details, there's some lovely prose they can go read in the `isFrobnicated` docs. And all of the complexity of "`A` or `B` if this or anything if that" is thrown into its own function, separate from everything else.

If `A` and `B` don't have a common supertype that you control, then you can always write a standalone function, an `implicit` class, or (if you're in Scala 3) a proper extension method. Take your pick.

Depending on your actual use case, there may be more that can be done, but this should be a start.